# Why does Express serve the static file through router, but breaks path to scripts folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

**Folder Structure**

```
app
├── app.js
├── public
│   ├── data
│   │   └── data.json
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       ├── filter-list.js
└── routes
    └── index.js
```

**app.js** correctly requires the index.js router

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(require('./routes/index'));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**routes/index.js** finds the file and serves it up

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.sendFile('/Users/Michael/Desktop/js-list-filter/app/public/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**public/index.html** refers to **filter-list.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/filter-list.js"></script>
```

**Issue:**
The router correctly serves up the index.html file, however the path to the script file is broken and keeps outputting a 404 error.

The reason I'm routing it with res.sendFile() is because this is just a test project to practice with pulling data from a MySQL database and outputting it on a single page, and using some scripts to manipulate that data. There is no need for multiple pages or views.

Comment: have you tried loading that js file directly in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `app.use('/', express.static('public'));` in your `app.js` file to set the public folder as your source for static client side assets.

Comment: I had it running like that initially and it does work. The problem with that is that there is no way (I think) to then connect to the database, run a query AND output that directly into the HTML. I assumed that routing it, then running the db connection in the router, performing the query then send it through the router was the way to go.

Comment: Just put your route that will perform the query before the route to the static folder. Routes are resolved in order and executes the first route that matches the given url pattern.

Comment: You might be confusing your method of serving data. You can either do: Server-side rendering of html or you an parse the data using Javascript on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

That is a really weird way of serving static files. Where have you seen that?

But to answer your question, your application is only serving the root path. I can only imagine that `res.sendFile()` is scanning your `/public` directory for anything that starts with `index` and therefore it will render your `index.html`.

What you actually want to do, is put the following line in your app.js once all the manual routing is done:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './public')));
```

Comment: "I had it running like that initially and it does work. The problem with that is that there is no way (I think) to then connect to the database, run a query AND output that directly into the HTML. I assumed that routing it, then running the db connection in the router, performing the query then send it through the router was the way to go. "

If its a weird way of doing it, could you point me in the right direction to achieve: capture db data, query then output to the DOM while still using the static method?

Comment: This may arguably not be considered as static file, because you want to populate a document based on data coming from a database, which generally is dynamic. Please have a look at Expressjs' documentation. Consider view engines and `res.render()`.

Comment: I had a feeling that was it... Just wanted to avoid using a view engine this time if I could get away with it. Thanks!